# How to connect and run Google Big Query to Tableau for my GA4 data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have connected Google Big Query to Tableau for my GA4 data. However, the data is split across several tables, each corresponding to a single day. How can I consolidate all these tables into a single, comprehensive table?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just Union the tables when setting up the connection? "New Union" is one of the options on that screenshot.